# Is function "isPayToScriptOut" unsafe?

Tags: plutus, transaction, datum, on-chain, datum-hash

As far as i understood, function **"isPayToScriptOut"** assumes every output that has a datum hash is a script output. But what if we create new output with datum, assigned to some pub key (for example due to use of: *"mustPayWithDatumToPubKey"* in off-chain code). So our new output wont be related to script one, but **"isPayToScriptOut"** will return true in this case? Because datum hash can be attached to any transaction. And that makes **"isPayToScriptOut"** not safe enough for development.

My deductions are correct?

*Here is considered function's code from plutus library:

```
 -- | Whether the output is a pay-to-script output.
    isPayToScriptOut :: TxOut -> Bool
    isPayToScriptOut = isJust . txOutDatum

    txOutDatum :: TxOut -> Maybe DatumHash
    txOutDatum TxOut{txOutDatumHash} = txOutDatumHash
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your deductions are partially correct. `isPayToScriptOut` looks at the credentials of an address [(1)](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/Plutus-V2-Ledger-Api.html#t:Credential) and return true if it is a script address, false if it is a public key credential. It thus does not look at the datum, it can deterministically check whether an output is made at a script address.

Here comes the crux, currently there are two types of scripts, native scripts and plutus scripts (V1 or V2). This function and the `credential` data type do not encode or differentiate between these scripts!

So in conclusion, you do know that that address is locked by a script, but you do not know what kind of script it is. It could be a native script locked by just a single public key.

This might change due to this CIP [(2)](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/pull/310). It aims to add a distinction between the types of scripts we have on the ledger.

**EDIT**
A previous version of plutus indeed did use the datum for this function [(3)](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/src/Plutus.V1.Ledger.Tx.html#txOutDatum). Note that this haddock host an outdated version of what is available in plutus. I would recommend using a local, up-to-date version. You can build this in the plutus-apps repo by entering a nix-shell and executing `build-and-serve-docs`.

Luckily, both the new plutus V1 [(4)](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/c8d4364d0e639fef4d5b93f7d6c0912d992b54f9/plutus-ledger-api/src/PlutusLedgerApi/V1/Tx.hs#L212) and V2 [(5)](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/c8d4364d0e639fef4d5b93f7d6c0912d992b54f9/plutus-ledger-api/src/PlutusLedgerApi/V2/Tx.hs#L136) implementations of these helper functions now implement it via the credentials. But note that the argument about it being unsafe due to not knowing what kind of script belong to a credential still holds.